# Get URL parameter from url query

Tags: reactjs

**Goal:** Retreive Id from URL

I have a feed of products with the following code:

```js
  <Router>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Feed} />
          <Route exact path="/" />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/product/:productId"
            component={DetailProductPage}
          />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
```

Here is my feed code:

```js
  <div className="feed">
      <div className="feed__cards">
        {products.map((product) => (
          <ProductCard
            image={product.image}
            brand={product.brand}
            name={product.name}
            id={product.id}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
```

And the `ProductCard` component that creates the URL:

```js
<div className="productCard__container">
        <img src={image} />
        <h1>{brand}</h1>
        <h2>{name}</h2>
        <p>{id}</p>
        <p>{<a href={`/product/${id}`}>View</a>}</p>
</div>
```

When I click on an individual product, I'm redirected to the individual product page:

```js
function DetailProductPage({ id }) {
  const productId = { id };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Product page</h1>
      <p>{id}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I go this route, I get a URL with the product parameter: (e.g., `http://localhost:3000/product/6CeJGSm7dBTABs8rRBJh`)

How do I query for the `6CeJGSm7dBTABs8rRBJh` part of the URL and put it into a variable?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using react-router-dom for this. There are a few ways you can retrieve this value from the URL, but the simplest approach with the provided code would be to use the `useParams` hook like so:

```js
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function DetailProductPage({ id }) {
  const { productId } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Product page</h1>
      <p>{productId}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

More info here: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams

Answer (score 0):

Look like the follwoing code grabs the product id from the URL:

```js
const params = useParams();
```

Answer (score 0):

While exporting component, you need to use `withRouter` to get access to this parameter:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
export default withRouter(ComponentName);
```

Your parameters are in `props` now. In you case:

```
const productId = props.match.params.productId;
```

or (using destructuring):

```
const { match: { params: { productId } } } = props;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the url by using the [Url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) object provided by javascript.

To get your current location you can use

```
window.location
```

So by combining Url and location

```
let urlArr = new URL(window.location).href.split('/');
console.log(urlArr[urlArr.length - 1]);
```

This will log **6CeJGSm7dBTABs8rRBJh**